# ios - Network / Internet Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking

After hours of searching on google I still cant find a single topic about this one:
1. I need to put error handling functions if the user does not have internet connection.
2. the user have internet connection but cant connect to the server .

And where can I put these? I tried one topic but it don't show the alert view message.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)getDataPressed
{
    if([myRequest_ isExecuting])
    {
        return;
    }

    if(myRequest_ != nil)
    {
        [myRequest_ release];
    }   
    myRequest_ = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_PATH]];
    myRequest_.delegate = self;
    [myRequest_ startAsynchronous]; 
}

#pragma ASI Delegate methods
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{    
    NSLog(@"Request finished successfully");
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);

    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [[request responseString]JSONValue];
    NSDictionary *arrayElement = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"user"];

    NSString *ID = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"id: %@",ID);
    NSString *usr = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"usr"];
    NSLog(@"usr: %@",usr);
    NSString *gd = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"gd"];
    NSLog(@"gd: %@",gd);
    NSString *ag = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"ag"];
    NSLog(@"ag: %@",ag);
    NSString *st = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"st"];
    NSLog(@"st: %@",st);
    NSString *lf = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"lf"];
    NSLog(@"lf: %@",lf);
    NSString *da = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"da"];
    NSLog(@"da: %d",da);

    for(NSString *value in [arrayElement allValues]){
        NSLog(@"Found Value %@",value);     
        label.text = [value stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,",ID,usr,gd,ag,st,lf];

    }
}
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{   
    NSLog(@"Error %@", [request error]);
    if([request error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Destination Unreachable" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
   }
}
-(void) dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thanks to those who will help ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try the [Reachbility](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) application to help you out checking if you have internet or not. As for the server itself, you can use the [NSUrlConnection Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) methods to check if there was a problem with your request (by seeing the kind of HTTP code that comes)

Comment: is it ok to use NSURLConnection even if im using ASIHTTPREQUEST?

Comment: I think it should work the same way (I too use ASIHTTPRequest) sometimes. I do think they have 2 methods, one for success and another one for the failure. Although I have receive HTTP responses code 400 on the success method.

Comment: can u please explain it more sir.. and oh by the way when i am trying reachability at first before execution it dont give a response even in the console.... hows that

Comment: When you set use ASIHTTPRequest you need to say who is going to be the delegate (in other words: who is going to receive the responses from the server). You then need to implement two methods, one for the success and another one for the failure.

Comment: You can check here how to use it: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use. For the Reachability you can check this tutorial: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/14/checking-network-reachability-iphone/

Comment: i tried to put the reachability before execution but it really dont respond even in the console. here is the code that i insert : `-(void)reachability {
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];    
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Internet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Connection OK");
 return;
}
}`